# Compress redundant/overlapping array data

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, compression, lossless-compression

Imagine a million or more arrays that overlap in data (sometimes more and sometimes less). The data is always sorted in ascending order. A single value comes at 2 bytes.

Here are some examples:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I guess it would be possible to perform some sort of substitution:

```
A = [1, 2, 3]

[0, A, 4]
[0, A, 5]
[A]
[A, 4]
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

This should already help a lot but maybe a different substitution could have saved even more? Of course, run-length encoding is an option as well though the substitution approach probably yields better compression due to the huge amount of redundant information.

Additional requirements:

- Lossless compression
- Should be fast to decode/uncompress
- Should be fast to encode/compress (though decode/uncompress speed is more important)
- Random access of the data

How could an algorithm look that does this? Any better ideas? Really is just about how to store the data in a way that consumes the least amount of space while still being readily available.

EDIT:
The numbers are not always consecutive. It might as well look like this:

```
[0, 1, 7, 12, 13, 15]
```

The data is however not random but shows repeating sequences.

Comment: Are the numbers always consecutive?

Comment: No. There can be gaps such as [0, 1, 7, 12, 13, 15]

Comment: You're going to need to decide how many arrays you are going to support. If it's a million (roughly 2^20), using A, B, ... isn't going to cut it. Have you tried just using ZIP compression, IIRC, it's pretty good at handling runs

Comment: I haven't because I still need to allow for random access. Though maybe it would be worth to chunk the data (but would also reduce the compression ratio again).

Answer (score 1):

first of all, is compression even needed? If the arrays are at around 10 items that would be around 44 bytes per array, so a million arrays would only be about 44Mb, not a critical amount with modern systems.

If this is to much I would suggest testing something like lz4 compression. This is made to be fast, and while it does not allow random access it should give an estimate of how efficiently the data could be compressed.

For small arrays the object overhead can take more memory than the data itself. if you do not need to add/remove items you might consider some scheme to keep all the data one or two lists. For example like adding all numbers to one continuous array and using a struct with offset/length represent each sub-array. This should let you reduce the overhead significantly. Use `Memory<T>` or `Span<T>` if you want to return a sequence without any copying.

This also conveniently lets you reuse existing sequences if possible. Just add sequences in sorted order, longest first, and do a search to see if the sequence is already represented. In your example, inclusive the non consecutive example we could represent the sequences as follows:

```
numbers: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 7, 12, 13, 15]
offset:0 length: 5
offset:0 length: 6
offset:1 length: 3
offset:1 length: 4
offset:2 length: 4
offset:6 length: 6
```

A problem with a substitution scheme as you suggest is that it seem difficult to do without an array for each item, and that uses a minimum of 32 bytes, so not very good if each array is short, but possibly better if arrays are significantly longer than in your example.

Comment: I already managed to cut down the size a lot by using run-length encoding and storing a single byte for the delta but I'm still trying to see whether even larger savings are possible because the redundant data looks very exploitable here. Your idea looks very interesting and I haven't thought about such an approach myself.

Comment: Arrays could be significantly longer. However I'm not exactly sure how I'd best find repeating sequences because if I was just hashing the content I'd just find perfect matches even though maybe just one additional number is in the other array, etc. I guess theres many permutations.